# Menu contents not displaying on mobile on Main page only

Tags: magento2, menu, mobile

Magento 2 Mobile menu issue.

My content of my menu on my mobile page (containing my navbar links) does not appear in the expanding menu on the mobile version of my site. All that I get is a black background.

This issue only occurs on the main page of my site, any secondary pages display this menu perfectly.

When I inspect the element everything shows as being present an when I add a z-index of -1 to the background in my dev console and then deselect it, I see my contents for a split second before it's gone again.

Anybody experienced this? Possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Please check **browser's console** for any **js errors**.

It can also be any **css conflict problem** on home page. So you also need to match css which is being applied on main page and other page (where every thing is working fine).

**Note:** First you need to check for javascript errors in browser. If there is no such error for javascript, then you need to debug with applying css.

Comment: no js errors in console...

Comment: Then you need to check whether some css style is overriding your css.